# Expected ']' in regular expression for IE 8 document mode :IE 8 standards

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer

When using

```
var re =  new RegExp (openTagString + "([\\s\\S]*?)" + closeTagString + "|\\$\\{(.*?[^\])\\}", "g");
```

getting error like `"Expected ']' in regular expression".[only for IE 8 & document Mode : IE8 standards]` in other versions of IE its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you included `\` itself in that last character class, you needed to quad escape it like this:

```
var re =  new RegExp (openTagString + "([\\s\\S]*?)" + closeTagString + "|\\$\\{(.*?[^\\\\])\\}", "g");
```